# Run gradle test from another gradle task

Tags: spring, gradle, junit

I created Spring Boot project which uses gradle build system. I want to run one separate test class by custom gradle task to be able depend on it in other tasks. Now I can do it with this code:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

def gradleWrapper = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? 'gradlew.bat' : './gradlew'

task runMyTest(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "$rootDir"
    commandLine gradleWrapper, ':test', '--tests', 'com.example.MyTest'
}
```

Obviously, this is not a very beautiful solution, because it launches an additional Gradle daemon. I tried before another solution:

```
task runMyTest(type: Test, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    include 'com.example.MyTest'
}
```

But it is not working (do not execute my test class).

**UPD**: I tried yet another solution:

```
task runMyTest(type: Test) {
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching "com.example.MyTest"
    }
}
```

It fails with this error message:

```
Execution failed for task ':runMyTest'.
> No tests found for given includes: [com.example.MyTest](filter.includeTestsMatching)
```

However, obviously, my test exists, since running the test through the command line produces the correct result.

**UPD2**: I missed `useJUnitPlatform()` inside my test task. It was in the default test task (written to my build.gradle by Spring Boot initializer), but not in the custom task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using a [TestFilter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestFilter.html).

Using `includeTestsMatching` you can specify your class.

If you need to specify a single test method, you can use `includeTest "com.example.MyTest", "someTestMethod"`.

```
task runMyTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching "com.example.MyTest"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and got error:

Execution failed for task ':runMyTest'.
> No tests found for given includes: [com.example.MyTest](filter.includeTestsMatching)

Comment: @kiv_apple it means the filter is not including your test class. To check if I'm correct, if you comment all the `filter { }` block, the tests are run correctly?

Comment: No. It doesn't fail, but just does nothing (actual test isn't executed).

Comment: @kiv_apple Try two things. 1. If you execute `runMyTest --dry-run` the task `testClasses` is included in the task graph? 2. If you execute `runMyTest --rerun-tasks` are your tests being executed? (both of them commenting the `filter { }` block)

Comment: If I execute `--dry-run` the task `testClasses` is included in the task graph. If I run `--rerun-tasks` my test is not executed.

Comment: Maybe it is important - my test class marked with `@SpringBootTest` annotation, my test method marked with `@Test` annotation

Comment: @kiv_apple I can't understand why it shouldn't work. I even tried it myself now and it's working correctly. If you launch `test --dry-run` and `runMyTest --dry-run` and you compare their task graphs, you see exactly the same tasks apart from `test` and `runMyTest` ?

Comment: Yes, I have exactly the same task graphs for these tasks. May be runMyTest have another test search directory for some reason? Also my tests written in Kotlin. May it be a problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210504/discussion-between-giorgio-antonioli-and-kiv-apple).